# Need to count them items from a list

Tags: python, list, count

i need your help :)

I have got a big log file called access_log.log with lot of lines like these (without the blank lines):

```
85.55.242.1 - - [22/Jan/2013:15:56:59 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico hxxp/1.1" 404 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/10.04 Chromium/18.0.1025.168 Chrome/18.0.1025.168 Safari/535.19"

85.55.242.1 - - [22/Jan/2013:15:56:59 +0100] "GET /frutos.swf hxxp/1.1" 200 1454441 "hxxp://www.joquese.cat/frutos.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/10.04 Chromium/18.0.1025.168 Chrome/18.0.1025.168 Safari/535.19"

85.55.242.1 - - [22/Jan/2013:15:56:59 +0100] "GET /plujasecs_mudo.flv hxxp/1.1" 200 1325949 "hxxp://www.joquese.cat/frutos.swf" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/10.04 Chromium/18.0.1025.168 Chrome/18.0.1025.168 Safari/535.19"

88.2.214.254 - - [22/Jan/2013:16:25:23 +0100] "GET / hxxp/1.1" 200 2722 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/536.26.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.2 Safari/536.26.17"
```

I'm "fighting" with python to extract the referrers from each line and list them with the numbers of copies from the 50 most common. I know it will be so easy with "awk" but I want to learn how to do it with python. What I have done is to mark the blank space as a field separator and take the strings between the fields number ten and eleven.

```
arxiu_de_log = open("access_log.log","r")
linies = arxiu_de_log.readlines()
arxiu_de_log.close() 

clean_log=[]
for line in linies:
    try:
        separador_de_linea=line.split(' ')
        camp_de_referer = separador_de_linea[10:11]
        clean_log.append(camp_de_referer)

    except:
        pass

print clean_log
```

When I run the program what I get is:

```
[['"-"'], ['"hxxp://www.joquese.cat/frutos.html"'], ['"hxxp://www.joquese.cat/frutos.swf"'], ['"-"'], ['"hxxp://www.joquese.cat/"']
```

But I would like something similar to:

```
2   "-"

1   "hxxp://www.joquese.cat/frutos.swf"

1   "hxxp://www.joquese.cat/frutos.swf"

1   "hxxp://www.joquese.cat/"

....
```

I have tried to program the counter with something similar to:

```
import collections
...
counter = collections.Counter(clean_log)

for count in counter.most_common(50):
    print(str(count[1])+"\t"+ str(count[0]))
```

But I can't make it work properly, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use lists with `Counter`, only hashable types. Why do you put the referrers in lists anyway?

```
import collections

with open("access_log.log","r") as arxiu_de_log:
    clean_log = [
        (line.split(' ')+[None]*10)[10]
        for line in arxiu_de_log]

counter = collections.Counter(clean_log)

for count in counter.most_common(50):
    print(str(count[1])+"\t"+ str(count[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are quite close to having what you want. One thing to keep in mind is that `separador_de_linea[10:11]` is a list, whereas `separador_de_linea[10]` is a string. I think you want the string:

```
import collections
count = collections.Counter()
with open("access_log.log","r") as arxiu_de_log:
    for line in arxiu_de_log:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            separador_de_linea = line.split()
            camp_de_referer = separador_de_linea[10]
            count[camp_de_referer] += 1

for referer, cnt in count.most_common(50):
    print('{} {}'.format(cnt, referer))
```

yields

```
2 "-"
1 "hxxp://www.joquese.cat/frutos.swf"
1 "hxxp://www.joquese.cat/frutos.html"
```

This saves memory by avoiding the creation of the `clean_log` list.

---

Tips:

- Instead of

  ```
  arxiu_de_log = open("access_log.log","r")
  ```

  use a
  [with-statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)

  ```
  with open("access_log.log","r") as arxiu_de_log:
  ```

  The file will be closed when Python's flow of execution leaves the
  with-statement. Thus you don't have to (remember to) call

  ```
  arxiu_de_log.close()
  ```

  explicity yourself.
- Avoid calling readlines() whenever possible, since this loads the
  entire file into memory, and creates a Python list of all the lines.
  Don't do this unless you need all the lines held in memory at the
  same time. In many instances, all you need is one line at a time. So
  instead of

  ```
  linies = arxiu_de_log.readlines()
  ```

  use

  ```
  for line in arxiu_de_log:
  ```
- It's a bad habit to use bare `except` in `try...except` statements.
  It will catch more than you expect, such as `KeyboardInterrupt` and
  `SystemExit` exceptions. The best practice is to only catch the error
  you want to handle. In this case

  ```
  try:
      ...
  except IndexError:
      pass
  ```

  would be better.

Comment: Unutbu your code works very well but with my low "skill" i understand better the Daniel solution and i only can check one "answer".

Comment: don't know why this answer was not chosen, it is the cleanest and actually correct.

Comment: As i said beferore, both are correct, but with my low skill i understand better the first one. I would like to check both but i can't.